# Process and measurement covariance in EKF

Tags: robotics, kalman-filter, slam

What is a *practical* way to find process/measurement covariances in EKF?  I may have some ground-truth data for this task.

Also, how does non-constant measurement time intervals influence the above covariances?

Comment: Could you clarify 'I may have some ground-truth data'? How accurate is that ground-truth? Are you working with real sensor data, or on simulated data?

Comment: I work with real sensor data. By ground truth I mean some external (accurate) tracker.

Comment: @AlexKreimer, for measurement covariance matrix, take a look at the datasheet of your sensor. It provides you with the standard deviation. For the process matrix, I don't think there is a way rather than your knowledge about the system. It is a matter of tuning.